# java process consuming more RAM than total RAM

Tags: linux, java, ram

I have a server with docker container containing java processes. One of process is consuming memory more than 100%(117%) visible in top command.

```
$ top
...
MiB Mem : 515396.0 total, 149379.3 free, 135893.8 used, 230123.0 buff/cache
Mib Swap: 32768.0 total,   32768.0 free,      0.0 used. 171544.5 avail Mem
...
    PID USER PR NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S %CPU  %MEM    TIME+ COMMAND
3103558 root 20  0 9449.8g 590.5g 588.0g S 28.1 117.3 21786:42 java
```

I crosschecked using ps aux command but RSS and VSS values are even higher.

```
$ ps aux | grep 3103558
root 3103558 26.3 99.9 9908790360 619223404 ? Sl  Sep29 21788:59 java ... -Xms196G ...
```

in free -g used memory is lesser.

```
$ free -g
          total     used    free    shared  buff/cache  available
Mem:        503      132     145       200         224        167
Swap:        31        0      31
```

When I checked in our jconsole memory is under control as given in java_opts max heap value (10,926,161,920 bytes).

Can someone suggest me why some process consuming memory more that 100% and do I need to panic or it is some expected condition ?

Comment: Please do not post screenshots, when plain text will do.